# How can i communicate that certain element of a data-record is only available in newer versions of the data?

Tags: forms

I have an ERP system which manages invoices. That system didn't store the inventory, items where taken from, for a specific invoice prior to a specific version, so for all invoices created earlier this data can't be displayed.

I'm not sure how i should present this circumstance to the user.

- Idea 1, skip it:

  ```
  Name:      John Doe 
  Date:      27. May. 1966
  Items:     ...
             ...
             ...
  ```
- Idea 2, empty fields:

  ```
  Name:      John Doe 
  Date:      27. May. 1966
  Inventory:
  Items:     ...
             ...
             ...
  ```
- Idea 3, generic "n/a":

  ```
  Name:      John Doe 
  Date:      27. May. 1966
  Inventory: N/A (or "not available")
  Items:     ...
             ...
             ...
  ```
- Idea 4, explanation:

  ```
  Name:      John Doe 
  Date:      27. May. 1966
  Inventory: This data only available for invoices made after (version|date)
  Items:     ...
             ...
             ...
  ```
- Idea 5: Display N/A and a tooltip containing the lengthy explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially an error message, so it should follow the simple rules:

- explain what has happened in human language (e.g. "The data is only available before/after DATE")
- provide directions how to resolve it, if any (e.g. "You can request it manually from X.")

Comment: I completely agree with your suggestions, but I would not call this an "*error*".  An error connotes something more spurious and something that can be fixed, whereas this will always be present.  A better term might be "*note*".  Of course, what you call it really only matters if the user is going to see the term (e.g. "Error:  The data [...]" vs. "Note:  The data [...]").